# Displaying as much text as possible within a fixed height

Tags: javascript, html

Is there an algorithmic way to say in PHP (if not, in JS) : « In DIV X, display as much text as possible from string Y but do not go beyond height Z » ?

Comment: PHP won't know the size of the text as it is displayed on the user's browser. If you want to modify the actual contents you will need to do so with JavaScript, if you just want to have a fixed size for an element with the the overflowing contents hidden, you can just use `overflow:hidden` in your style.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use CSS? Simply set the font size on a static text (lorem ipsum), and set the overflow of the div X to hidden. Once done, remove the test text and fill div X dynamically. If I haven't understood your question, please correct me :)

Comment: Due to fonts, sizes, units, line heights and countless other variables you'll never be able to do it server-side. In Javascript there may be a way to render text and measure the height in pixels. This answer is the best method IMO

Comment: Ok but I want to display « ... » at the end of the displayed text, besides with an overflow the last line could be cut (with the top half of the letters visible and the rest invisible) isn't it ?

How to get around these 2 issues ?

Comment: The best thing I can suggest is to write a method, which cuts the first x letters of the content (you can find x based on static text) and fill the Div X with that text. Don't forget to consider not cutting a word in the middle ;)